# Skipping gap periods the x-axis of a chart python

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I would like to customize the x axis of a pyplot line chart. Basically, I have periods without values, so I want to skip these periods.

[image: Example Image]

Data example:

| Row | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| previous | 2021-5-10 14:58 | 100.520 |
| previous | 2021-5-10 14:59 | 100.500 |
| red dot | 2021-5-10 15:00 | 100.550 |
| green dot | 2021-5-11 9:00 | 100.490 |
| after | 2021-5-11 9:01 | 100.650 |
| after | 2021-5-11 9:02 | 100.480 |

```
def chartValueTimeLine(time_series, value_series, line_color='blue', time_label='date', value_label='y_label', alpha_value=0.35, title='chart1'):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12.5, 7), num=title)
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    plt.plot(time_series, value_series, label=value_label, color = line_color, alpha=alpha_value)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.xlabel(time_label)
    plt.ylabel(value_label)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
```

I would like the green point to come directly after the red one in the x-axis. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: can you share an sample of the data, e.g. the segment corresponding to your image?

Comment: Hi, I added some data to clarify what I mean. In the x-axis I have a 9 hours gap, between the red point and the green point, meanwhile the gap between the other points is just a minute

Comment: hard to replicate without my own dataset but I used a pandas dataframe to plot the above sample data and I didn't have a gap? maybe try that if you haven't already. also I know the mplfinance module has something for skipping non trading days, which may be worth checking out. alternatively if you want to paste your code here then people can give specific help on what you've tried.

Comment: I added the code. Ok, I'm printing using lists. I'll check the mplfinance module.

Comment: I have the same problem, and would be happy if someone finds a solution. I'd rephrase that I would want to cut out the period between red and green dots from the x-axis. My data is not equidistant and I want the x-scale to remain a datetime-axis (with gaps)